# Android: Floating Action Button appears with transparent background

Tags: android

I've added `FloatingActionButton` to my application with a png icon `ic_send`. When I was testing using gingerbread device it keeps showing the button with no background color, but on lollipop its showing OK.

Here is my **Activity** code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import butterknife.Bind;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Bind(R.id.toolbar)Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    }
}
```

And here is my **xml file**:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/dp10"
        android:background="@color/card"
        android:gravity="center"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/dp5">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/main_edt_from"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp30"
                android:hint="@string/amount"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_next"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/dp15"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_send"
    app:elevation="2dp"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/card"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

My **build.gradle** config is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kr.currencyconverter"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 4
        versionName "2.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
}
```

What I have tried is adding `app:backgroundTint="@color/accent"` to the  `FloatingActionButton` but it didn't works.

Here is an image to show what I mean.. in testing I get a transparent button
[image]

Comment: Please try giving some back ground color to Floating Action Button in XML to avoid transparency.

Comment: @dex I've added app:backgroundTint="@color/accent" but it didn't works

Comment: give `android:alpha="1.0f"` for fab and check

Comment: @Jolson it didn't work

Comment: @KhalilRumman try some other color, will it be visible ? and please add color to floating XML.

Comment: @dex actually no it didn't work. but what I did is changing the targeted sdk to 22 instead of 23 and I changed the dependencies also. and it works, 
so I think there is new proprieties should be available with marshmallow support design library

Comment: it's a weird, lets report to google as a bug.

Comment: @dex how to report to Google?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list , then click on new issue and file bug.

Comment: It was fixed in version 23.1.0 of support library, Like @KhalilRumman said.

Answer (score 0):

you must set

```
app:backgroundTint="@color/yourcolor"
```

Comment: i think `Tint` cannot be applicable to version lesser than `Lollipop`

Answer (score 0):

attach this icon here

```
"@dimen/dp15"
```

there seems to be background color present in this image.

Comment: can you explian? I've did this already android:layout_margin="@dimen/dp15"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_send"

Comment: I meant, the image android:src="@drawable/ic_send", check whether it has background color.

Comment: can you try setting ic_send as button background

Comment: actually it is PNG without background. I reported to Google and it was a bug in support library 23.0.1 and now should be fixed in 23.1

Comment: Good to know. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with FloatingActionButton(FAB). In my case I was using fragments in Activity and I had FAB in my activity's layout file. So fragment renders on top of FAB. So I had to add `fab.bringToFront();` in `onPostResume()` method in my activity to get it work.

```
@Override
protected void onPostResume() {
    super.onPostResume();
    fab.bringToFront(); // fab - reference of FloatingActionButton
}
```

Also, Check elevation of the layout should be smaller than FAB's elevation.

Comment: it was a bug in support Library 23.0.1 and it was fixed from Google and now it works fine.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

remove app:elevation="2dp" on FloatingActionButton

```xml
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/dp15"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_send"
        //app:elevation="2dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/card"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />
```

Instead, Use given snippet

```xml
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/dp15"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_send"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/card"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your code, but can you please add an explanation of why and how it works to your post?

Comment: elevation is how we setup our layer on layout. FloatingButtonAction has default value for elevation = 6dp. so if you set elevation = 2dp, background will appear on background of your layout. minimum elevation for FloatingButtonAction is 6dp to show up on top layer of layout. Correct me if I'm wrong