# How to properly draw Android FloatingActionButton instances that are part of a ViewGroup

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I'm trying to build an Android custom view that consists of multiple `FloatingActionButton` (namespace `android.support.design.widget`) instances that are arranged in a circle.

To do so I create a new view that inherits from `ViewGroup`. The code looks as follows:

```
package myapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.ColorStateList;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import myapp.R;


public class ButtonOverlayView extends ViewGroup
{
  private final float _radius = 200.0f;
  private int _desiredSize;


  public ButtonOverlayView(Context context)
  {
    super(context);
    initializeViewGroup(context);
  }


  public ButtonOverlayView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
  {
    super(context, attrs);
    initializeViewGroup(context);
  }


  public ButtonOverlayView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
  {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    initializeViewGroup(context);
  }


  @Override
  protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
  {
    _desiredSize = 600;
    measureChildren(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(_desiredSize, _desiredSize);
  }


  @Override
  protected void onLayout(boolean b, int i, int i1, int i2, int i3)
  {
    layoutChildren();
  }


  private void initializeViewGroup(Context context)
  {
    createChildren(context, getIconIdentifiers(), getColorIdentifiers());
  }


  private void createChildren(Context context, int[] iconIdentifiers, int[] colorIdentifiers)
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < iconIdentifiers.length; i++)
    {
      final FloatingActionButton button = new FloatingActionButton(context);
      button.setImageResource(iconIdentifiers[i]);
      button.setSize(FloatingActionButton.SIZE_NORMAL);
      button.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
      button.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(colorIdentifiers[i]));
      button.setClickable(true);
      addView(button);
    }
  }


  private void layoutChildren()
  {
    int buttonCount      = getChildCount();
    int center           = _desiredSize / 2;
    float angle          = 0.0f;
    float angleIncrement = 360.0f / (buttonCount - 1);

    FloatingActionButton button = (FloatingActionButton)getChildAt(0);
    int halfWidth  = button.getMeasuredWidth()  / 2;
    int halfHeight = button.getMeasuredHeight() / 2;
    button.layout(center - halfWidth, center - halfHeight, center + halfWidth, center + halfHeight);

    for(int i = 1; i < buttonCount; i++)
    {
      button         = (FloatingActionButton)getChildAt(i);
      halfWidth      = button.getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
      halfHeight     = button.getMeasuredHeight() / 2;
      double radians = Math.toRadians(angle);
      int x          = (int)(Math.cos(radians) * _radius) + center;
      int y          = (int)(Math.sin(radians) * _radius) + center;
      button.layout(x - halfWidth, y - halfHeight, x + halfWidth, y + halfHeight);
      angle += angleIncrement;
    }
  }


  private int[] getIconIdentifiers()
  {
    final TypedArray icons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.icons);
    int[] iconIdentifiers  = new int[icons.length()];

    try
    {
      for(int i = 0; i < icons.length(); i++)
      {
        iconIdentifiers[i] = icons.getResourceId(i, -1);
      }
    }

    finally
    {
      icons.recycle();
    }

    return iconIdentifiers;
  }


  private int[] getColorIdentifiers()
  {
    final TypedArray colors = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.colors);
    int[] colorIdentifiers  = new int[colors.length()];

    try
    {
      for(int i = 0; i < colors.length(); i++)
      {
        colorIdentifiers[i] = colors.getResourceId(i, -1);
      }
    }

    finally
    {
      colors.recycle();
    }

    return colorIdentifiers;
  }
}
```

Icons and colors for the `FloatingActionButton` are provided in a dedicated xml file with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <array name="icons">
    <item>@android:drawable/ic_delete</item>
    <item>@android:drawable/ic_input_add</item>
    <item>@android:drawable/ic_menu_call</item>
    <item>@android:drawable/ic_delete</item>
    <item>@android:drawable/ic_input_add</item>
    <item>@android:drawable/ic_menu_call</item>
    <item>@android:drawable/ic_delete</item>
  </array>
  <array name="colors">
    <item>@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item>@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item>@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item>@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item>@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item>@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item>@color/colorAccent2</item>
  </array>
</resources>
```

Technically it all works, i.e. it compiles and shows up when integrated in the Android app. However, when rendered the `FloatingActionButton` instances look "strange".

The following screenshots illustrate what I mean with "strange":

Phone 1 (Android 8.1):

[image]

The left screenshot shows all buttons in the unclicked state while on the right screenshot the lower right button is clicked.

Phone 2 (Android 9):

[image]

Same as above, left is the unclicked state, right shows the lower right button clicked.

Does anyone have an explanation why those buttons look "strange"? And how would I correct that issue?

**Edit**

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33208684/) SO question I took a closer look at the dependencies that I'm using which are as follows:

```
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1
com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1
com.android.support:support-annotations:+
com.android.support:design:25.3.1
com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1
```

Because it could potentially be a bug in those libraries I upgraded them to `28.0.0` but the optical result is still the same as in the screenshots above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I found the issue. What isn't quite obvious in the screenshots is that the buttons are actually transparent. This is happening because `getColorIdentifiers` does not properly retrieve the colors from the xml file.

As a result, the method `setBackgroundTintList` causes the buttons to become transparent. The solution is to correct the method as follows:

```
private int[] getColorIdentifiers()
{
  return getContext().getResources().getIntArray(R.array.colors);
}
```